# which statistical test to use to compare 3 different types of regions?

Tags: biostatistics

I want to compare the percentage of a species in 3 different types of regions. Which statistical test should I use??

Comment: That depends on what property of the groups you wish to investigate, and you said nothing about that other than that you wanted to "compare" them.  Specifically, do you want to test something like $H_0 : p_1 = p_2 = p_3$ versus $H_a : \exists \, i \ne j \; s.t. \; p_i \ne p_j$?  Or do you want to do contrasts?  It's up to you.  Then, depending on the nature of your hypothesis, consider what distributional assumptions you are making.  That will influence the type of test to use.

Comment: I want to do contrasts. to show that the one region is different from the other. I guess I have to do one-way ANOVA but I don't know much about statistics, so I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Marascuillo [test](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section4/prc474.htm) enables us to simultaneously test the differences of all pairs of proportions when there are several populations under investigation.